# Disclosure of USA visa refusal

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

I was refused US visa in 2007 using a manual passport. I cannot find the passport and the refusal letter.now I'm applying for Irish visa.does it matter?

Comment: Do they ask about *all* previous refusals, irrespective of how long ago?  If so, you must disclose the refusal and provide what details you can remember.

Answer (score 3):

The [AVATS guide](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-visit-ireland/giving-your-details-on-avats-for-a-visa-preclearance-application/#immigration-history) from the immigration department states :

> > You will then be asked if you have ever been refused permission to
> > enter Ireland. Have you ever arrived at a Port of Entry to Ireland and
> > been refused entry by an Irish Immigration Officer? This will include
> > any time you were refused entry to Ireland by an Irish Immigration
> > Officer after travelling to Ireland with a visa, without a visa, with
> > preclearance, or without preclearance.
>
> > Have you ever been deported from Ireland, or received notification
> > that you are subject to Deportation?
>
> > Have you ever been refused a visa for a country, other than Ireland?
>
> > Have you ever been refused entry to, deported from, or otherwise asked
> > to leave a country other than Ireland?
>
> If you answer ‘Yes’ to any of these 4 questions, you **must** give
> details, including the country concerned, dates and the reason.

---

If you don't remember the reason for the refusal, you may want to file a request for visa records to the Department of State.

How to do so is explained on this DoS [website](https://foia.state.gov/Request/Visa.aspx)